# What is the title of this samurai movie?

Tags: identify-this-movie

The movie starts by a samurai walking through woods and practising his skill (he makes a few steps and then cuts through air). I also remember that a lot of the story revolves around him living in a remote house that he finds on his way (wondering around) where he stays and helps out. If I remember correctly in the house lived a woman that would make him food all the time, and I think one older man that was a bit crazy and a few other people..

I think the movie was in color and it looked like it was more than 20-25 years old.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it - [After the Rain](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181960/plotsummary). It seems like I got the description wrong since he was not wondering through the woods, but just practicing there, and he didn't find a house but it was his own house and his wife and the house was actually an inn.. Also, the movie is from 1999, so it's not as old as I thought it was but oh well, at least I figured out which movie it was.

Here is [the scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHo8lCA65dQ) where he practices while walking through woods. It's quite easy to remember this scene since it lasts for 3+ minutes.